# List Various Model Attributes in Model Choice Field in Django Chosen Forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Sample(models.Model):
    sample_ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.sample_ID

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from chosen import forms as chosenforms
from .models import Sample

class SampleLookupForm(forms.Form):
    Sample_ID = chosenforms.ChosenModelChoiceField(queryset=Sample.objects.all())

class SampleNameLookupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        samples = Sample.objects.all().values_list('sample_name', flat=True)
        sample_tuple = [(i, i) for i in samples]
        self.fields['Sample_Name'] = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(sample_tuple)
```

Here I have two forms, one of which I would like to show all sample IDs in the drop down menu. The other I would like to show all of the sample names.

For the Sample IDs, this is easy because I have defined the unicode method to return the sample ID. However, I have no clue how to adjust the model, form, or view to create a drop down menu that contains the sample names (i.e. a model attribute other than that returned in the unicode method.)

How do I allow for model choice fields to display model attributes other than that defined in the unicode method?

Or, should I define the unicode method such that depending on certain conditions it returns a certain model attribute.

I should mention, here I am using [django chosen forms](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-chosen) which behaves very similarly to Django model forms, just with some added functionality.

The specific error message I am getting with the following code is:

```
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, it's better for your class fields to have all lower case, underscore separated names.

Comment: Right good catch that is convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about your `ChosenModelChoiceField`, I'm assuming it's a subclass of `ModelChoiceField`, you should overwrite `label_from_instance` method on the field:

```
class BlahChoiceField(chosenforms.ChosenModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        # return whatever text you want
        return obj.sample_name
```

Then for the definition you do:

```
sample_id = BlahChoiceField(queryset=Sample.objects.all())
```

[django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

**Edit**:

Your original code is on the right path, but your code is wrong on this line:

```
self.fields['Sample_Name'] = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(sample_tuple)
```

It should be:

```
self.fields['Sample_Name'] = chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(choices=sample_tuple)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this.

In your model "Sample" define some methods:

```
@staticmethod
def name_choices():
    return [s.name_choice() for s in Sample.objects.all()]

def name_choice(self):
    return self.sample_name, self.sample_name
```

And then your form would be:

```
class SampleNameLookupForm(forms.Form):
    sample_name =  chosenforms.ChosenChoiceField(choices=Sample.name_choices())
```